# Cordova & Firebase Authentication "location.protocol" Error

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use Firebase with Cordova to provide login methods via Google, Facebook and standard email and password combination. I have implimended the code using the tutorials in the Firebase docs (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova) however, I recieve the following error when I run a compiled Android version...

> "Uncaught Error: This operation is not supported in the environment this application is running on. "location.protocol" must be http, https or chrome-extension and web storage must be enabled.", source: https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.0/firebase-auth.js (6)"

When I run the same code in the browser it works flawlessly. I understand that this is because of the way Cordova serves the code on the Android device since it doesn't have its own domain. I have added the "universal-links" 
and "AndroidLaunchMode" configurations to my config.xml.

I am also only using the signInWithRedirect() function not signInWithPopup() as I am lead to believe that is not supported in Cordova.

Can anyone shed some light on this issue? I am using the latest Cordova and Firebase SDK 4.12.1.

Thanks,
Dylan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are initializing your Firebase app `onDeviceReady`. It is probably getting confused about the current environment.

Comment: Thank you, I was waiting until the page was ready to run the code but I was initializing firebase before the ready command. Which forced it to run locally causing the error. Thank you for your help!